# Inherit from code-block defined class in page/usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

**TL;DR**

Is it possible to replace the `Inherits="..."` of a `UserControl` using a class defined in a code-block, rather than the class in the compiled code-behind?

---

I have an ASP.NET web application that I quickly need to patch, but I am only allowed to update the `.aspx` and `.ascx` files... it is not possible for me to re-compile and release `.dll` files (due to the change management processes the client puts on us).

In the application I have a `UserControl` that is set to `Inherit` from the code-behind class for the file... but there is a bug in that class.

What I want to do is re-create the entire class within a `<script runat="server"></script>` block in the `.ascx` file with the appropriate bugfix.

I've tried the following, but I get...

> Could not load type 'MyCtrlStatic'.

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="MyCtrlStatic" %>
<script runat="server">
  Public Class MyCtrlStatic
    Inherits UserControl
    Public Function DisplayValue() As String
      Return "Hello World"
    End Function
  End Class
</script>
<div><%=DisplayValue()%></div>
```

The control in question is using a lot of different properties and methods from the code-behind class, and the above is a massive simplification of the issue.

Is this possible to achieve?  Otherwise I'm looking at re-building and going through an entire change management procedure.

Comment: _"it is not possible for me to re-compile"_ If that would work, it has to be re-compiled anyway

Comment: @Tim - I see what you mean... damn.  I was hoping there would be an obvious solution that I was completely missing.  Oh well.  Thanks

Comment: @Tim - if you're interested, I've solved it... see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44889997/930393)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face, and I couldn't see it until just a few minutes ago...

Instead of trying to declare a new `Class` and inherit from it, the answer is to inherit directly from `UserControl` and then have the code directly in the code-block.

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="UserControl" %>
<script runat="server">
  Public Function DisplayValue() As String
    Return "Hello World"
  End Function
</script>
<div><%=DisplayValue()%></div>
```

In addition the above, I also had to add a few `Import` command, such as...

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
```

But now I have a patched `.ascx` file that doesn't require the rebuilding of the DLL to work